# Use jQuery to load and display an offisite javascript file using form input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Part of my rescue's website is displaying a set of content based on a javascript source that is provided by our shelter managing software. They don't have an option to filter results on the fly via the software. SO I created separate javascript files on their site based on a certain set of filters before-hand. I'm trying to use a basic radio button form to select the different pre-filtered results and have it display the div associated with each using jQuery. Here is what I have and it works partially at [pricelesspetrescue.org/test-page](http://pricelesspetrescue.org/test-page/)

```
<html>
<head>
<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
function displayForm(c) {
    if (c.value == "2") {    
        jQuery('#claremontdogContainer').toggle('show');
        jQuery('#chdogContainer').hide();
    }
        if (c.value == "1") {
         jQuery('#chdogContainer').toggle('show');
         jQuery('#claremontdogContainer').hide();
    }
};
</script>

</head>
<body>
<label>Please select a location to view:</label>
<form>
    <input value="1" type="radio" name="formselector" onClick="displayForm(this)"></input>Chino Hills
    <br>
    <input value="2" type="radio" name="formselector" onClick="displayForm(this)"></input>Claremont
</form>

    <div style="display:none" id="chdogContainer">
    <script src="https://toolkit.rescuegroups.org/j/3/FzemP6HU/toolkit.js"></script>    
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
    </script>
    </div>

    <div style="display:none" id="claremontdogContainer">
    <script src="https://toolkit.rescuegroups.org/j/3/4ANRW3x8/toolkit.js"></script>    
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
    </script>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

What isn't working is the incoming javascript isn't complete. The results are shown but if, for example you go to [pricelesspetrescue.org/adoptable-dogs/](http://pricelesspetrescue.org/adoptable-dogs/), you can see that clicking on an individual result will load a popup that shows details about that result. It's as though it loaded the results but then turns off leaving unable to manipulate anything after that. Is it just not possible to run the two different formats on the same page? How can I make both work?

The javascript files SHOULD have the added functionality of being able to click on the results and it open a details popup. This is functional if I only load the javascript by itself `<script src="https://toolkit.rescuegroups.org/j/3/4ANRW3x8/toolkit.js"></script>` without the jQuery stuff. This is what is used on the live site at pricelesspetrescue.org/adoptable-dogs . There is no additional coding there to make the results clickable. I'm loading exactly this in the divs but it doesn't work.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want. These javascript files are loaded regardless of visibility of divs wrapping them. You should use Ajax to load content.

Comment: The javascript files SHOULD have the added functionality of being able to click on the results and it open a details popup. This is functional if I only load the javascript by itself `<script src="https://toolkit.rescuegroups.org/j/3/4ANRW3x8/toolkit.js"></script>` without the jQuery stuff. This is what is used on the live site at http://pricelesspetrescue.org/adoptable-dogs/ . There is no additional coding there to make the results clickable. I'm loading exactly this in the divs but it doesn't work.

Comment: You want to load a javascript file dynamically? And must be without jQuery?

Comment: It definitely does not HAVE to be jQuery. I just wasn't sure of a better way and yes I would like it to load dynamically since there are separate "results" per script file and I don't want to have them be on completely separate pages.

Comment: The title suggests that you want to use jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For loading scripts dynamically using "pure" Javascript, you need to use Ajax and `eval`.

```
function loadXMLDoc() {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE ) {
           if(xmlhttp.status == 200){
               eval(xmlhttp.responseText);
           }
           else if(xmlhttp.status == 400) {
              console.log('Error 400')
           }
           else {
               console.log('Unexpected error')
           }
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.open("GET", "https://toolkit.rescuegroups.org/j/3/FzemP6HU/toolkit.js", true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Or using jQuery.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://toolkit.rescuegroups.org/j/3/FzemP6HU/toolkit.js",
    context: document.body,
    success: function(result){
      eval(result);
    }
});
```

**Don't** forget to remove `script` tags from HTML.

Comment: The jQuery model definitely seems cleaner and more like what I'm looking for. I guess I'm not understanding how to load the second result based on a form selection in either case though.